# MSBUILD failing with error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core-sdk

I have a net48 SDK project (library), and on my build machine it has suddenly stopped building (and re-running prior commits fail).

Where does MSBuild look for the Microsoft.NET.Sdk for a .net framework (not core) project? I think it may have actually have been deleted, but I can't be sure since I don't know where to check....

Update: server needed updates installed, rebooted and installed updates,  and now everything is working again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that the 32-bit `dotnet` (in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`) was coming before the 64-bit one (in `%ProgramFiles%`). Swapping them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`dotnet sdk`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks) installed on your build machine.

SDK-style projects - even when targeting full FW - need `dotnet`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview for more details.

Btw. [Binlog viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) and binary MSBuild log (produced via `-bl` option) is a great tool to troubleshoot your build issues.

Comment: I had the dotnet sdk installed

Comment: There can be multiple factors influencing the sdk resolution - global.json, environment variables (specifically [sdk resolver vars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables#dotnet_msbuild_sdk_resolver_)), custom sdk resolvers, etc.

The binlog viewer can be of a great help to track what's happening in your case

Comment: global.json was my issue.  For the sdk version, set a specific version: get it from: dotnet --info

Comment: e.g. 7.0.401  for "sdk" version, and others like 7.0 or just 7